# How to send cookie value in an outbound HTTP Request in Mule

Tags: mule, mulesoft

How to send a cookie value in Mule?

I tried setting it as cookie=name=value under headers.

Comment: Do you mean in a Mule application? Which version of Mule? Please share the HTTP Request in XML text format.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mule 4.x and the latest HTTP connector (recommended) the headers section should look similar to this (in the XML view):

```js
<http:headers>
    <![CDATA[#[
        output application/java
        ---
        {
            "Cookie": vars.name++"="++vars.value
        }
    ]]]>
</http:headers>
```